# Rails efficiency of where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, where-clause

I'm worried about the efficiency of this line in the controller of my Rails project

```
posts_list = Post.where(:title => params[:title])
```

If the number of "Posts" in the database grows, will the line become slow to execute? Is there any possible optimization?

Comment: Little contrived example: you'd better use something like `LIKE`:
 `where('title LIKE ?' , "%#{params[:title]}%")` to provide more flexibility.

Comment: @jdoe How does `LIKE` provide more flexibility?

Comment: `params[:title]` can have `ruby` and you'll find even `Post`s with `ruby on rails` in their titles, not just with `ruby`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just fires this query,

```
select * from posts where title = params[:title]
```

You can index the title column in your migration file

```
add_index(:posts, :title)
```

Comment: This is right -- it's an exact match lookup so will tend to be very fast.  It's quite possible that the database will *implement* the index by hashing the title and storing the (short) hash, thus reducing string comparison cycles, but that should be transparent to you.  I wouldn't be worried about this kind of lookup until you're searching in the millions of records.

Answer (score 2):

Add index on title field can be a first approach :

```
class AddIndexTitleToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      add_index :posts, :title, uniq: false
    end
end
```

And you can use find_each on your iteration for prevent your database growing

```
Post.where(title: params[:title]).find_each(batch_size: 10) do |post|
    ...
end
```

That all for applicative enhancement